# Generate two RSA keys in the same code in C

Tags: c, openssl, segmentation-fault, rsa

I'm trying to generate multiple RSA key in C but I'm facing a segmentation fault with the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main () {
    RSA* keys = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM* e = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUM));
    BN_generate_prime_ex(e, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    int r = RSA_generate_key_ex(keys, 2048, e, NULL);

    RSA* keys2 = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM* e2 = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUM));
    BN_generate_prime_ex(e2, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    int r2 = RSA_generate_key_ex(keys2, 2048, e2, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

However, the following code seems to work well :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main () {
    RSA* keys = RSA_new();
    RSA* keys2 = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM* e = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUM));
    BIGNUM* e2 = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUM));
    BN_generate_prime_ex(e, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BN_generate_prime_ex(e2, 16, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    int r = RSA_generate_key_ex(keys, 2048, e, NULL);
    int r2 = RSA_generate_key_ex(keys2, 2048, e2, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why?

I really want to implement the first solution because my RSA generation is in a function.

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you use `BN_new()` instead of `malloc()` to allocate space for `BIGNUM` (I am pretty sure that's what you are supposed to do).

Comment: That solved the issue @EmployedRussian, thanks

Can you explain the difference between allocating memory with `malloc` and with `BN_new` ?

Comment: How did your code compile? You should have gotten an error that `BIGNUM` is an incomplete type.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include all the libraries I used when I copied the code. I also have : 
`#include <openssl/bn.h>`

I edited the initial message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this statement does not correctly initialize the `BIGNUM`:

```
BIGNUM* e = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUM));
```

Instead, one should do this:

```
BIGNUM* e = BN_New();
```

> Can you explain the difference between allocating memory with malloc and with BN_new ?

The source for [BN_New](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_lib.c#L230) shows that it does a bit more than `malloc` -- it zeroes out the memory and sets a flag.

P.S. Using recent OpenSSL, the original program doesn't compile (even after adding the missing `#include <openssl/bn.h>`). The developers have hidden the definition of `BIGNUM`, so this mistake is no longer possible.